# Can someone help me understand this plot?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, garch

I am struggling to understand the outcome of DCC GARCH correlations in this plot. I don't understand how the y-axis points are the same even though the correlations look like they are moving over time?

I tired replicating the DCC part of another code ([see link](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/econ589multivariateGarch.r)) and I'm getting the same result for my variables. Any help is much much appreciated!
Thanks.

[image: aph]

Comment: The values vary by less than $0.0000001$ (perhaps much less - who knows?) and so the scale fails to indicate the differences

Comment: Thanks @Henry I understand that but does it even make sense to report this result as time-varying correlations? In my report, I am arguing, based on literature, that DCC GARCH is a superior model to CCC or Pearson's as it considers changes in market conditions over time. But with such a narrow margin in my DCC estimates, will my argument stand?